# jquery selector performance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Just curious about which of these would be faster?

```
$('ul.dropdown a').first().click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

or

```
$('.dropdown > li > a').click(function(event) {           
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: the second one will be faster..

Comment: Well, they do two different things...

Comment: Moreover, if there's a difference for the machine, I doubt there's one for the human browsing the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They do two different things.**

I guess you're asking about `>` V.S. space:
`>` is fatser then space, as it goes one level deep only.

The tip with selectors is make the right side of it more precise than the left.
[Read more here](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sizzle%20selector%20tip%20right&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG4QFjAA&url=http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/&ei=ysGrT8e1G6Oy2wXH1cimAg&usg=AFQjCNHTFeLgTQLY28twIrDRyhkE0eVx6Q)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown').find('a').on('click', function(e) {           
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Could you update your answer sharing why that might be fastest?